# How do I have create two Front Ortho Viewports with different reference images on each?

Tags: image

I know how to create front and back ortho views and get a different image in each, but I want them both to face the same way rather than them be mirrors of each other. How is that done in 2.8? I know this is possible in previous versions of Blender because I've seen it a tutorial. I made this video with details here - https://youtu.be/MBJtgHXZMPE

Comment: Hey :). The video only captured your Adobe Premiere window so it's not very useful. Check your recoding settings ;)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know :-) . Yes I had the tutorial imported in Premiere as it can slow the time-lapse video tutorial with great control on the playback. Trouble seems to be that windows doesn't capture the full screen mode in premiere. Doh!

Answer (score 2):

You can use "Local Collections" filters in each viewport to filter out your different backrounds.

Place each of your images in a different collection.

Place your work objects in a third collection.

[image]

Create 2 viewports by click-dragging the edge of the 3D viewport.

Expand the "N" panel, then go to the "View" panel, go down to "Collections" and check "Local collections" in both viewports.

Now click the eye icon of the background collections in each viewport.

Result :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can split your viewport, then hover with your mouse over them and press for one viewport <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>  (Front) and for the other one <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> (Back). Hover with your mouse over the viewport and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> , select Image and Background.

This image appears only in the selected viewports background and only in the selected orthographic view.

Do this for both viewports with separate images.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you can't anymore, but you can:

[image]

Add an array modifier, shift you object thanks to it and enable *"on cage"* button.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @lemon. This looks very promising. However, I don't understand "Add an array modifier, shift you object thanks to it and enable "on cage" button."

Comment: Having a background image per viewport is no more available (afaik). So this answer is just a trick. If you use an array modifier that will duplicate the object (you can do it with duplicate linked also). And if "on cage" is on, you have the ability to use vertices on the original and in the copy.

Comment: Thanks @lemon. I'm sure this is something really simple but I'm having trouble implementing it still. https://youtu.be/TDfrC1ojnzc

Comment: I think the object/empty you've used for the array is rotated and scale. Just move it instead.

Comment: sorry, I'm not familiar with the array modifier and I'm not sure how to get it to produce an image of the inside in the viewport. I have been looking for tutorials that show how to do this and can't find any. Can you clarify further?

Comment: I think I understand now. The images are side by side!